# place div image relative to image size

Tags: html, css, image

I have following spritesheet

[image]

I already figured out, how to select specific elements out of it like this

```
<div class="rune" 
  style="position:relative;
         height:48px;
         width:48px;
         background: url({% static "rune_sprite.png" %}) -384px -192px">
</div>
```

But now I want to insert this sprite into another image, relative to the height and width of another image, like that image for example

```
<img src="{% static "rune_page.jpg" %}"/>
```

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

EDIT: I want it to look like this for example:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, can you elaborate?

Comment: @putvande I edited my question. The selected sprite should be at a specific place of the greater image

Comment: I think it can be done by setting position:absolute and z-index greater than the 'greater image'. Can you provide a JSFiddle to test with?

Comment: @AhsN Ok I made a little JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o776wunx/. I will try to figure something out with this z-index though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a parent with the `position:relative.`

The runes will have `position:absolute.`

Each rune will have its own `left` and `top` values.

Each rune class (`rune-1`, `rune-2`, `rune-3` etc.) will have its own `background-position`.

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
[class^="rune-"] {
    position:relative;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTCrY.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.rune-1 {
    background-position: -384px -192px;
}
.rune-2 {
    background-position: -719px -193px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVVYd.jpg" />
    <div class="rune-1" style="left: 36px;top: 268px;"></div>
    <div class="rune-2" style="left: 39px;top: 186px;"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3my2wwau/1/)

Comment: Wow this answer is awesome :) What does that `"rune-"` mean though?

Comment: In short, `[class^="rune-"]` takes all classes starting with `rune-`. So you can have rune-1 for image 1, rune-2 for the other background-position's etc. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/3my2wwau/1/

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for your larger image you want to make a div and give it a background image set the height and width and then give it `position:relative;`

This will be the main wrapper that your rune graphics go in.

Now give your ruin's `position:absolute;` and use the axis to set where on the parent you would like them to sit:

```
top:10px;
right:10px;
bottom:10px;
left:10px;
```

What's happening here is relativity. I wont go into massive detail about how relativity works but basically you have your ruins that are positioned absolutely relative to its parent.